# Insert query is not working | Syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am using this query to insert values, but it is not working.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (type, weight, side, size, quantity)
            VALUES ($stock_type, $weight, $side,$size,$quantity)";
```

In Database table 'value type' is varchar for all values

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Sigh... quotes. What's the value of `$tbl_name`?

Comment: try to echo $sql; and run it mysql and the result.

Comment: type, weight, side, size, quantity are all int type?

Comment: Some advice, *don't* concat or interpolate variables in SQL queries.  Use prepared statements.

Comment: I try to run it into mysql but this error displaying   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (type, weight, side, size, quantity) VALUES (10, 15, 3,6,1)' at line 1

Comment: in some version(old) of mysql type is a Reserved Word.

Comment: @BigTech: `order` is a reserved word in MySQL.  Surround it in backticks, ``INSERT INTO `order` (...) VALUES (...)``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the column types but you need to quote values for string type fields:

```
$sql='INSERT INTO $tbl_name (type, weight, side, size, quantity)
            VALUES ("$stock_type", "$weight", "$side", "$size" , "$quantity")';
```

Comment: You got your quotes mixed up.  You need double quotes around the query, so that the variables will interpolate.

Comment: for integers we dont need quote.

Comment: I run your query . but it display same query like this... INSERT INTO $tbl_name (type, weight, side, size, quantity) VALUES ("$stock_type", "$weight", "$side", "$size" , "$quantity")

Answer (score 0):

If any of those columns are char, varchar or date you need to quote them.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (        type,   weight,    side,  size,  quantity)
           VALUES           ('$stock_type', $weight, '$side', $size, $quantity)";
```